# iOS integrate photos app

Tags: ios, native, using, photos

I'm developing an iOS app. I get collection of images from web, store them in Documents directory and want to be able to show them, say, as facebook app shows your photos. I think it uses native photos app of iOS. I've searched in apple docs and googled, but with no result. So, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't use the native photos app. It has built its own toolkit for that and have even open sourced their toolkit - [`Three20`](http://three20.info/). It does have support for creating photo galleries for content based on the net so I imagine this will suit your use case. You can get started off by looking at [`tutorials`](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=three20+framework+tutorials) already available on the net along with their documentation. Specifically look at [`this`](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-photo-gallery-three20/).